# How to rescue this QA

Tags: discussion, editing

[Applescript Won't Invoke Shortcut Command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208746/applescript-wont-invoke-shortcut-command)

This entire QA, including all 3 answers & a myriad comments, is more of an online troubleshooting conversation than a true QA.

The final answer I feel was worth the journey, even if the OP didn't actually help a great deal in the process - most of the replies were along the lines of "it no werky"

Serves me right, I suppose, but sometimes tenacity pays off - even if the OP has now wandered off & the final answer will probably never be marked as correct.

I think we now have a nice answer to the reworded title, how to look for a checkmark on a menu item & only perform an action if true/false
It's certainly something I didn't know how to do until now & it is likely to be something I'm going to recycle in future.

Anyone have any suggestions - or even a burning desire to edit it into shape?
I'm not really sure what should stay or go - for instance, my entire first answer ends up not being what the OP wanted because of the, at that time, uncertainty of the initial toggle state.

Alternatively, should I abandon this to the mists of time & just make a new QA that simply asks & answers the underlying question of how to check & act on a menu toggle?
I reverted the title in anticipation of this alternative solution.

Comment: I would go for a new question and answer, the old one looks like quite a monster to edit.